# probability distribution question .1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

on average a bowler takes a wicket every eight overs. what is the probability that he will bowl ten overs without succeeding in a getting a wicket?

Comment: That’s a strike rate of $48$ (balls bowled per wicket taken), which is bloody impressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a Bernoulli experiment, and we want to know that probability that event "not getting a wicket" occurs 10 times in a row. The probability that it occurs on any one trial is $7/8$, so we need to raise $7/8$ to the tenth power.

Does that make sense?

Comment: it does so far , but i was wondering if we can solve it using the binomial formula{ N ncr x * (p)^x * (1-p)^n-x }

Comment: You can. You could use $p=1/8$, $N=10$ and $x=0$, or you could use $p=7/8$, $N=10$ and $x=10$. The first way is asking for the probability of $0$ wickets in $10$ attempts; the second asks for the probability of $10$ non-wickets in $10$ attempts.

Comment: Well thanks a lot , i actually did that but i was like " it couldn't be that simple" :D

Comment: When $x$ in the binomial formula equals either $0$ or $N$, then it all reduces to either $(1-p)$ or $p$ just being raised to the $N$ power.

Comment: yea that's make sense , since n ncr 0 = 1 and p^0 =1 so what is remain is 1-p to the power of n { 1*1*(1-p)^n = (1-p) ^n } . Thanks again :3